# spark-submit: unable to get driver status

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-standalone

I'm running a job on a test Spark standalone in cluster mode, but I'm finding myself unable to monitor the status of the driver.

Here is a minimal example using spark-2.4.3 (master and one worker running on the same node, started running `sbin/start-all.sh` on a [freshly unarchived installation](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) using the default conf, no `conf/slaves` set), executing `spark-submit` from the node itself:

```
$ spark-submit --master spark://ip-172-31-15-245:7077 --deploy-mode cluster \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    /home/ubuntu/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.3.jar 100

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverClient' on port 36067.
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to ip-172-31-15-245/172.31.15.245:7077 after 29 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver successfully submitted as driver-20190627090828-0008
19/06/27 09:08:28 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... waiting before polling master for driver state
19/06/27 09:08:33 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... polling master for driver state
19/06/27 09:08:33 INFO ClientEndpoint: State of driver-20190627090828-0008 is RUNNING
19/06/27 09:08:33 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver running on 172.31.15.245:41057 (worker-20190627083412-172.31.15.245-41057)
19/06/27 09:08:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/06/27 09:08:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-34082661-f0de-4c56-92b7-648ea24fa59c
```

```
> spark-submit --master spark://ip-172-31-15-245:7077 --status driver-20190627090828-0008

19/06/27 09:09:27 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://ip-172-31-15-245:7077.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: Unable to connect to server
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:148)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.requestSubmissionStatus(RestSubmissionClient.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.requestStatus(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: No response from server
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.readResponse(RestSubmissionClient.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.org$apache$spark$deploy$rest$RestSubmissionClient$$get(RestSubmissionClient.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$requestSubmissionStatus$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:152)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:227)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient.readResponse(RestSubmissionClient.scala:278)
    ... 13 more
```

Spark is in good health (I'm able to run other jobs after the one above), the *driver-20190627090828-0008* appears as "FINISHED" in the web UI.
Is there something I am missing?

**UPDATE**:
on the master log all I get is

```
19/07/01 09:40:24 INFO master.Master: 172.31.15.245:42308 got disassociated, removing it.
```

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Also checking! Facing the same problem here